# How to remove all folders with foldername X within a directory using osx terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory

There is a folder named X located within a number of subfolders of root directory Y. I want to delete all folders named X that are present in Y and all of it's subfolders. I want to do this using **osx Terminal**.

The folder can be located anywhere downstream of Y at any level, so I want to use a more systematic approach than just using `rm -r` for every locations I find.

Answer (score 34):

"cd" to root of directory Y

then (assuming the folder name is "X", type in):

"`find . -name X -exec rm -rf {} \;`" (and be incredibly careful about where you start this "`find`" from... you only want to do this within your Y directory).

I do this kind of thing all the time to remove old/busted repository directories (like "`.svn`"), which I suspect is what you may also be doing as well.

And now would probably be a smart time for me to remind you that "Time Machine" is a great thing to have enabled on your Macintosh.

Comment: +1 super fast you typed all those in just under 1 minute

Comment: you're usually faster than me, @Anoop; and I do this kind of "find / rm" all the time, but like I said it's super dangerous without Time Machine enabled.

Comment: I am actually using this in a research project. I have a large MRI dataset consisting of 2D and 3d volumes which were placed on an  external hard drive. I need to extract only a certain set of data/subfolders. What I want to do is to delete all folders except my target folders.

Comment: well that's a different (or opposite) question than what you asked above...

Comment: It is part of the approach. I wanted to know how to delete specific subfolders, so that the end product is a directory that contains only the folders I need. If there is a more productive way to do this I would like to know.

Comment: Is it also possible to implement multiple names, besides X, into one query? This way I could remove all subfolders that are not of interest to me in one go.

Comment: ask this as a separate question (e.g. "how to remove all subfolders *except ones with foldername X* using Terminal") and let's see if I can answer it faster than @Anoop

Comment: done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785981/how-to-remove-all-subfolders-except-ones-with-foldername-x-using-terminal%20

Comment: `-type d` will help you filter only directories!!